# ajax DELETE method not allowed

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to delete user with scim service.

When I call it through SoapUI and curl it works but when I create ajax call it returns 405 method not allowed

**SOAPUI5**

*IP:*
https://localhost:9447//wso2/scim/Users/token_of_user_to_be_deleted

*OAUTH2 token:* my_token_for_oauth

*Media type:* application/json

**CURL**

curl -v -k --user admin:admin -X DELETE https://localhost:9447/wso2/scim/Users/b228b59d-db19-4064-b637-d33c31209fae -H "Accept: application/json"

This both worked and deleted the user.

**AJAX DOESNT WORK FOR ME**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://localhost:9447/wso2/scim/Users/token_of_user_to_be_deleted',
    type: 'DELETE',
    headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },

    beforeSend: function (request) {
            request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + that.oauth2.loadToken().access_token);
    },


    success: function() {
        console.log("success")                        
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("error")
    }
});
```

**ERROR:**
Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Filter: Unsupported HTTP method: DELETE

Comment: Probably your webserver needs to add the appropriate CORS headers in the response to the ajax call. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS Ajax requests cannot by default do all the same things that a regular HTTP request can, mostly for security reasons. The solution is to set the appropriate response headers on the server to allow it, and also to allow the necessary HTTP methods, usually including OPTIONS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser does hit an `OPTIONS` request before sending the actual request. This request includes the accepted methods

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS
```

Your server does not send a `DELETE` accepted method in the options response, hence your request throws this error.

To solve this issue, you need to add the `DELETE` to the accepted methods by your server. in your server settings

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS
```

The options request is only sent on the browser since it is only implemented by the browsers as a security measure. curl / node / SOAPUI5 do not confirm to this restriction, hence enable you to get what you want. (unless the server is configured otherwise internally to prevent some headers)

## Update

As @jannis mentioned, It's worth noting that the `OPTIONS` request preceding the actual one is called a **preflight request** and the mechanism in general is called **CORS**.

You can read more in preflight requests (and CORS in general) by following these links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control#Preflighted_requests
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: It's worth noting that the OPTIONS request preceding the actual one is called a preflight request and the mechanism in general is called CORS. You can read more in preflight requests (and CORS in general) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control#Preflighted_requests)

Comment: awesome, i'll add it to the answer.

Comment: thank you for your very helpfull response @AhmadBamieh